# Why are the leader dots in the table of contents typeset in math mode?

Tags: table-of-contents, tex-core, tocloft

Here is a general kernel question. I am wondering why the leader dots are typeset in math mode.

While experimenting with my own sectioning commands, I had alignment issues with the dots. Does it have something to do with alignment?

```
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
            \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
            mu$}\hfill
```

Anyway, I tried it like

```
\leaders\hbox{
            \kern .8em\hbox{.}\kern .8em}\hfill
```

and it seems pretty decent.

From the kernel latex.ltx:

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

Note that `tocloft` keeps this

```
\providecommand{\cftdotfill}[1]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{\cftnodots}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \hfill
  \else
    \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern #1 mu\hbox{\cftdot}\mkern #1 mu$}\hfill
  \fi
}
```

Comment: The leader dots are not really typeset in math mode, since the `\hbox` escapes it to text mode (in the current font).

Comment: Read p 371 of [`source2e.pdf`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This goes back to plain TeX and `\dotfill` which is defined as

```
\def\dotfill{\cleaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern1.5mu.\mkern1.5mu$}\hfill}
```

LaTeX2.09 used the same definition, as did the first couple of releases of 2e.
Then:

```
% \changes{v1.1u}{1996/10/28}{Removed math mode}
```

The current 2e definition is

```
\def\dotfill{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
  \kern\z@}
```

In LaTeX `\@dottedtocline` is a kind of extended `\dotfill` the 2.09 defintion used math mode as in the original `\dotfill`. In 2e though here we removed the math setting of the actual `.` but left the muskip spacing, probably so that the existing `\@dotsep` parameter still worked.

```
%  \item[|\@dotsep|] Separation between dots, in mu units.
%                  Should be |\def|'d to a number like 2 or 1.7
```

The removal of math mode `.` was even earlier than in `\dotfill`:

```
% \changes{v1.0k}{1995/04/25}{Added \cs{hbox} around dots.}
```